# Why keyboard-waffles image for Page Not Found page

Tags: discussion

why [this](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflowmeta/img/keyboard-waffles.jpg) image is attached in the Page-Not-Found Page ?. 
Is this image meaningfull ?. 
Is the image in this page is static or dynamic ?

[image]

Comment: Because waffles.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19480/305867

Comment: Case we haven't found a replica of such device... we must have it, we keep it to honor all of those keyboard waffles we haven't enjoyed

Comment: that's not special. I have [this one](http://i.imgur.com/aqxO2Cj.png) as 404 image for a car rental website of a friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the general theme of Stack Overflow to keep these types of error messages "fun". While I am not certain of the exact reason for this, I would assume it is basically a way for errors to feel less like features breaking and more like side story.

Let's be honest, the waffle keyboard started you down a very interesting rabbit hole. First, waffles. Secondly, it brought you to [the many memes of meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19480#19480) (this link should echo like Monty Python while being read).

Overall, the point is to provide a better user experience, and that is why you see an epic waffle keyboard. You're welcome.

<sub>*error images may vary depending on time and severity*

<sub>this is an unofficial response</sub></sub>